# Android - Emulator: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: android, android-studio

I moved my Android Studio away from my C drive over to my F drive to save up on space but now I'm having trouble running my app to test it with Android Emulator.

event log image

[image]

> Emulator: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/Robin/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/options/updates.xml"

The location where this file is situated is actually in F:/Android/.AndroidStudio3.1/...

How do I tell the emulator to check at that location instead?

- I've added an environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME with value F:\Android
- I've set custom paths in idea.properties in AndroidStudio/bin
- I've set the gradle path to F:/Android

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

ATM, The only solution I know to fix this was to create a symbolic/hard link for the original file into the directory where android emulator looked it up. Well, that's how I fixed this issue. My guess was the search path for the emulator was hard coded into android emulator source. That's only my guess though.

So, in your case, just create a copy / symlink (recommended, as updates.xml often got modified by Android Studio on update) like this maybe (pardon me, as I'm not a windows user).

```
mklink C:/Users/Robin/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/options/updates.xml F:/Android/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/options/updates.xml
```

Well, I'll update my answer in case I get a better solution for this. BTW, I hope this can be any help for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the right solution, in devices already created before the folder move, you have to change (in each) the path folder in the related .ini files, locate in the new .android/avd folder.
Example:

```
path=C:\Users\Name\.android\avd\EmulatorName.avd
```

to

```
path=D:\Android\.android\avd\EmulatorName.avd
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was happening with me. Was facing the external entity error. Tried a lot to solve it even tried uninstalling and reinstalling but nothing works. Then i tried locating each and every file associated with android studio including android studio project and there were many more stuff, was easy to find as all were in user of my c drive. I deleted each and every file , all the projects and the changes i have made to my android studio were deleted. Then i restarted the app. Works fine for me

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.
after clicked **File ---> Sync with File System**, it works

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I still have the same problem that it's looking at my C:/Users path rather than my F:/Android path.

13:22 Emulator: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/Robin/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/options/updates.xml"

Did I maybe do something wrong with setting the custom paths?

Thanks for your answer either way, any help is always appreciated!